# improve java code to avoid Heap out of memory exception

Tags: java, exception, heap-memory

I have the following piece of code where I am reading a large file using a stringBuffer object, performing some operations by creating temporary byte[] objects and because of this I get a out of memory exception when a have a large file size say 16 MB.

```
StringBuffer dataBuffer;
ArrayList<byte[]> sourceFragments;
ArrayList<BitSet> sourceBits = new ArrayList<BitSet>();
dataBuffer = eHelper.readFile(encoder.getFileName());
sourceFragments = eHelper.fragmentFile(dataBuffer.toString());
             /*
     * converting byte[] to BitSet
              the below loop is run 128 times
     */
    Iterator<byte[]> iter = sourceFragments.iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        byte[] temp = iter.next();
                    // temp.length will return 128 KB
        sourceBits.add(eHelper.byteArrayToBitSet(temp));
    }
```

I am wondring if there is a way for me to prevent this out of memeory exception to occur. I am not considering the option of increasing heap space, I am using the default heap space on a 32 bit machine. Is there any way I can reduce the number of temp objects that are being created so that I can avoid the outOfMemory Exception

edit1:

I have made the following changes to the code where I do npt load the entire file into the memory as a String, I do not create byte[] array, but read directly from the file and convert it directly to an arrayList of bitSet. This has helped a bit where I am able to work with 20 MB files, I am wondering if can push this further some more to work with a max of 30 MB files ?

edit2:

I have modified the source code in as follows, I have removed any redundant data types that I have created 
        public ArrayList fragmentSourceData(File filename) {
        RandomAccessFile r ;
        ArrayList sourceBits = new ArrayList();

```
    try {
        r= new RandomAccessFile(filename, "r");
        System.out.println(r.length());
        encoder.setSourceFileLength((int)r.length());
        int fragmentSize = encoder.calculateFragmentSize();
        System.out.println(fragmentSize);
        encoder.setFragmentSize(fragmentSize);
        encoder.setParameters();

        byte[] b = new byte[fragmentSize] ;

            long new_pos=0;
            int i=0;
            while(new_pos<=encoder.getSourceFileLength()){
                i++;
                r.read(b ,0, fragmentSize );
                 new_pos=fragmentSize*i;
                 r.seek(new_pos);
                 sourceBits.add(BitSet.valueOf(b));
                  }
               r.close();
               b=null;

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return sourceBits;
}
```

}

Comment: Why not create `BitSets` as you go rather than creating `byte[]`? That will minimise memory and work. i.e. it will be faster even if you have the memory.  Note: a PC with 16 GB costs as little as $1000 so perhaps its time to get more memory. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Seems kind of obvious, but why are you reading the whole file into memory? Why not read it 128KB at a time?

It's also not obvious what `fragmentFile` does.  How does it convert the String to `byte[]` fragments?

Comment: I am performing a series of operations after the steps above so I cannot read 128KB at a time

Comment: What data do these operations need? If you don't tell us what you actually need, we can't tell you what to get rid of.  You have the entire file in memory three times: as a StringBuffer, as a list of byte arrays, and as a list of BitSets - which of these do you actually need for further processing?

Comment: I really need the bitSet for further processing, I have changed te code so that I am loading the file as a string but reading from the file and creating bitSets as I go. Anything else I can look out for ?

Comment: Can you post the new code? Including any functions (like `fragmentFile`) - without knowing what that does, it's hard to know if you need the whole string in memory.

Answer (score 1):

- Why can't you increase the memory?
- All you are doing on dataBuffer is call toString on it, you can try to make fragmentFile() method to take the file name and return the sourceFragements you will save memory for both data buffer and the string that is created in toString().
- You can also have avoid creating sourceFragments array and instead try to directly create sourceBits from each byte[] that you read.

Comment: I will try this operation  monitor if there is a performance improvement

Answer (score 0):

There are a few areas of improvement in the code. Lets focus around the loop.

```
Iterator<byte[]> iter = sourceFragments.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
   byte[] temp = iter.next();
   // temp.length will return 128 KB
   sourceBits.add(eHelper.byteArrayToBitSet(temp));
}
```

there is no need to get the iterator for the ArrayList sourceFragments. You can convert the while loop to a [for](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) loop and simply loop on each record in the [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/list.html). The changes would look like the following.

```
for(byte[] val : sourceFragments){
   sourceBits.add(eHelper.byteArrayToBitSet(val));
}
```

Comment: the for loop will also implicitly create an iterator. Also generally iterators are implemented in a way that they don't allocate new memory but traverse the underlying collection. For example an iterator over a list may only require current index.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the default memory limit may be 64M (it depends on your JVM), so if you're reading a 16M file into memory, then converting that into a `List<byte[]>` also taking 16M and then converting it into a `List<BitSet>` that will also take 16M, then you are surely pushing the limit, as there are probably other things going on that also require some memory.

After the contents of the `dataBuffer` have been converted into a `List<byte[]>`, you could set `dataBuffer` to null explicitly. Then, in the loop, instead of using an iterator, you could loop over the List the old-fashioned way, allowing you to explicitly set each element to null after having converted it into a BitSet. Memory pressure should trigger a GC cycle that would clean up these unused datastructures.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the whole file into a stringbuffer seems like kind of a waste of memory unless you need it later.

Since you will need the full 16MB (even more when in memory) to store the bits of the file you will have to save some memory in the generation stage.

I'm not sure what kind of object eHelper is.
If sourcebits must be fragmented you could maybe try something like:

```
BITSET_MAX_SIZE = ...;

File file = new File("somefile");
int total = file.length();
InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
for (int bytesRead = 0; bytesRead < total;) {
    int currBitsetSize = Math.min(BITSET_MAX_SIZE, (total - read) * 8); // Can this be variable or should it be padded?
    BitSet bitset = new Bitset(currBitsetSize);
    for (int bitsetIndex = 0; bitsetIndex < currBitsetSize; bitsetIndex += 8) {
        int currByte = in.read();
        bytesRead++;
        for (int bitPos = 0; bitPos < 8; bitPos++) {
            if ((currByte & (1 << i)) > 0) {
                bitset.set(bitsetIndex + i); // Set the position to 1
            }
        }
    }
    sourceBits.add(bitset);
}
in.close();
```

I have not tried this my self, but something like that might work. Sorry if it is not the prettiest example.

Perhaps you cannot use new FileInputStream directly depending on the source, but you should get an inputstream and read byte by byte from that.

This code can definitely be improved upon since it won't be the most effective. You will probably want to read with in.read(byte[] buffer, int byteOffset, int byteCount).

Comment: I am using RandomAccessFile to perform the read operation thanks anyways for your suggestion